# extend object without modifying (functional extend)

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I've been using this extend:

```
const extend = require('util')._extend;
```

but just noticed it modifies the original object:

```
> let hello = {a: 5};
> extend(hello, {poop: 'whas'})
{ a: 5, poop: 'whas' }
> hello
{ a: 5, poop: 'whas' }
```

What's a concise way I can extend objects without modifying them?

E.g. I'd want the above repl session to look like:

```
> let hello = {a: 5};
> extend(hello, {poop: 'whas'})
{ a: 5, poop: 'whas' }
> hello
{ a: 5 }
```

Comment: All `extend` functions *extend* their first argument. You are looking for a  *copy* function it seems.

Comment: `extend({}, hello, {poop: 'whas'})` extends a new object (the object literal) not `hello`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Object.create`

```
const extend = require("util")._extend;

let hello = { a: 5 };
let newObj = _extend(Object.create(hello), { poops: 'whas' });

console.log(newObj.a); // a
console.log(newObj.poops);  // whas

console.log(hello.a) // 5
console.log(hello.poops) // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign) is your solution

```
const object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);
```

Comment: `util.extend` does the same as `Object.assign`.

Comment: I thought this doesn't do deep copies

Comment: Oh indeed it does the same, i didn"t know, thanks Bergi :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're using ES9/ES2018, the simplest solution is just to use the spread operator. It will generally compile down to Object.assign anyway, but it's a much neater syntax.

```
let hello = {a: 5}
console.log({ ...hello, foo: 'bar' })  // { a: 5, foo: 'bar' }
console.log(hello)                     // { a: 5 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody provided an ES5 solution so far, let me give this a shot:

```js
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
 if (!window.JSON)
  return false;

 var _res = JSON.stringify(obj1) + JSON.stringify(obj2);

 return JSON.parse(_res.replace('}{', ','));
}

var foo = { 0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'peach' };
var bar = { favorite: 'pear', disliked: 'apricot' };

extend(foo, bar); // returns bar
console.log(foo); // { 0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'peach' }
console.log(bar); // { 0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'peach', favorite: 'pear', disliked: 'apricot' }
```